# Lookup formula that matches data in row and column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to automatically lookup values andthe data is set like this:
First sheet

```
id1   id2   id3
data  data  data
empty empty empty
```

Second sheet

```
id1  data1
id2  data1
id3  data1
```

This is sheet is where i have id's as headers and i need to enter a formula which adds the data1 value in the empty cell from the second sheet to the first, if the id values match.

I have tried index & match so far, but either i am doing it wrong or it is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Wait you have the data like the second sheet and you want it to look like the first sheet or the other way around?

Comment: There are several examples of the use of index and match on here - and I supplied a couple...

Comment: I need a formula that automatically enters the data1 from the second sheet to the "empty" cell in the first sheet if the id number matches.

Comment: That would require array type formulas, if the data set is large then it would cause a major slow down.  VBA will be a better fit.

Comment: Right now the data set is quite small, but if you are able to tell me how to do both ways it would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong. The data in the look up vector weren't sorted in ascending order. After, i the simple LOOKUP formula worked perfectly. Regardless, thanks everyone for the tips and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You want `VLOOKUP` but your data would have to be organized in a vertical orientation to do so.

[This is a good tutorial](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) on VLOOKUP. It basically works like this:

- I have data in Column A, and I want to populate Column B with data from Column D, only if my Column A data shows up somethere in Column C
- I populate Cell B1 with `VLOOKUP(A1, C:D, 2, 0)`
- If A1 shows up somewhere in column C, I will get output from the adjacent Column D cell. So if A1 matches C6, then B1 would become D6.

Comment: Thats great, but i am not allowed to change the data, so i must find a way to compare one set of data which i set as a column with another which is set as a row.

Comment: @Solar Mike This is what i have right now, but it returns incorrect data:    
  
=LOOKUP(B1,'SC data'!$C2:$C4,'SC data'!$S2:$S4)

The B1 cell is the id1 i have mentioned above in the first sheet and the C2:C4 is supposed to be the lookup vector or in the example above the id1,id2.. in the second sheet and S2:S4 are the result vector or the data1 cells in the second sheet.

Any idea on what im doing wrong?